# How can I put `must_not` under `filter` in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to use `not equal` in my filter but it doesn't work `[13:24] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]`:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      
      "filter": [
        {
          "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
               "status" : "DECLINED"
            }
           }
        },
        {
           "term": { "type": "ORDER"}
         }
      ]
    }
  }
```

it works if I put the `must_not` under `query` like below. How can I put not equal in filter?

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "status": "DECLINED"
        }
      },
      "filter": ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be one more bool needed inside the filter ?

```json
/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
                "term": { "type": "ORDER"}
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "status": "DECLINED"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when I use `filter: [...]`, does it work as same as `filter: -> bool -> must`? so the query inside filter array works as `and`?